# Show a list of elements once an hashtag is written

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend

I noticed that some social networks (such as Instagram, Twitter) highlight words with hashtags or @ in blue and a list of tags or people comes up. I was wondering how I can replicate a similar effect in Angular.

By analyzing the page, I saw that everytime a new hastag is written, a new < span > tag is generated with the hashtag text inside, but I still can't understand how to implement this.
Even an idea on how to make it would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: They use a div with an attribute of contenteditable in order to appear like a regular textbox. The advantage of this allows them to find text such as #NASA and replace the text within a span element, with #NASA inside (applying any class or style to the span).

When spawning the dialogue, the text typed after the # is used to query the list of data.

Comment: Twitter is using the DraftJS library. You can start by studying this code written in React: https://github.com/facebookarchive/draft-js/blob/main/examples/draft-0-10-0/tweet/tweet.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dropdown from bootstrap or material and fill it with a *ngFor with an array of filtered items from an array of possible tags.

You can even have a regex for the filtered tags to match anything you want, here is an example:

```
public search: string = ''; // You will change this with some input.
getTags(): string[] {
    let searchRegex = new RegExp(this.search, 'gi');
    return this.options.filter((o: string) => {
            return o.match(searchRegex);
    });
}
```

And the only thing you have to do in your html is to put your getTags() in your *ngFor() like this and check if the user has been started writing in your search input.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="search !== ''">
    <span *ngFor="let tag of getTags()">
        {{tag}}
    </span>
</ng-container>
```

You can even get more of this by changing the input to start changing the search variable and get a message variable that will be checked for special characters to start filling the search with something like this:

```
public message: string = ''; // This will have the actual message.
public search: string = ''; // This will be the real variable that will get the 
tags.

checkForSearchInMessage(){
    if(this.message.includes('@')){ // The @ character could be anything.
        this.search = this.message.split('@')[1];
    }
}
```